# Can't Generate Json schema from POJO

Tags: java, json, jackson, jsonschema

I worked with a single POJO and it works fine,I decided to work in a bunch of java classes using FileUtils from  org.apache.commons to walk throw all java files directory and use get class() inside generateSchema() from Jackson module, but the output wasn't the expected.

I don't know where the problem comes from ?

input :

```
File dir = new File("./src/main/java/com/hiveprod/generator/jsonshema");
        String[] extensions = new String[] { "java" };
        System.out.println("Getting POJOs..." );
        List<File> files = (List<File>) FileUtils.listFiles(dir, extensions, true);
            for (File file : files) {
            String className=file.getName();
            //Mapping...
             ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            JsonSchemaGenerator generator = new JsonSchemaGenerator(mapper);

            JsonSchema jsonSchema = generator.generateSchema(file.getClass());
            StringWriter jsonSchemafile = new StringWriter();
            mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT, true);
            mapper.writeValue(jsonSchemafile, jsonSchema);
```

> > example of one file

output :

```
{
  "type" : "string"
}
```

expected output :

```
{
  "type" : "object",
  "properties" : {
    "result" : {
      "type" : "string"
    },
    "subtitle1" : {
      "type" : "string"
    },
    "infoSup" : {
      "type" : "string"
    },
    "subtitle" : {
      "type" : "string"
    },
    "title" : {
      "type" : "string"
    },
    "info" : {
      "type" : "string"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That peace of code below helps me to gets all classes within a given package

```
 private static Class[] getClasses(String packageName)
            throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
        ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
        assert classLoader != null;
        String path = packageName.replace('.', '/');
        Enumeration resources = classLoader.getResources(path);
        List dirs = new ArrayList();
        while (resources.hasMoreElements()) {
            URL resource = resources.nextElement();
            dirs.add(new File(resource.getFile()));
        }
        ArrayList classes = new ArrayList();
        for (File directory : dirs) {
            classes.addAll(findClasses(directory, packageName));
        }
        return classes.toArray(new Class[classes.size()]);
    }

      private static Class[] getClasses(String packageName)
            throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException {
        ClassLoader classLoader =Thread.currentThread()
       .getContextClassLoader();
        assert classLoader != null;
        String path = packageName.replace('.', '/');
        Enumeration resources = classLoader.getResources(path);
        List dirs = new ArrayList();
        while (resources.hasMoreElements()) {
            URL resource = resources.nextElement();
            dirs.add(new File(resource.getFile()));
        }
        ArrayList classes = new ArrayList();
        for (File directory : dirs) {
            classes.addAll(findClasses(directory, packageName));
        }
        return classes.toArray(new Class[classes.size()]);
    }
```

Learn more: https://dzone.com/articles/get-all-classes-within-package

Answer (score 0):

```
generator.generateSchema(file.getClass());
```

file is a File not the class you want. I think you need at least the Class, maybe even instantiate it:

```
Class c = Class.forName(className);
generator.generateSchema(c.getClass());
```

If you have to instantiate it, every class should have an empty default constructor and Reflection should get this one:

```
Constructor ctor = c.getConstructor(); // use c again
Object instanceOfTheClass = ctor.newInstance();
generator.generateSchema(instanceOfTheClass.getClass());
```

Comment: Didn't work ⌣̩̩́_⌣̩̩̀ , it said << Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: AdvancedSelect.java>> despite
it exist !

Comment: I will try it later at home, shouldnt be a problem at all.

Comment: I used Class.forName() with the full package name but NotFoundException still there !